# WooCommerce include a different product when customer selects certain variation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We have this product in WooCommerce called `Christmas Lighting Net | 2×1 METER – WARM WIT` in WooCommerce. We have set this to be a product with different variations, namely `Including extension cable` and `Excluding extension cable`.

When the customer selects `Including extension cable` from the drop-down, I want this variation to include the extension cable product in our store which has a separate SKU altogether.

What's the best way to have this product included in the variation when it is selected from drop-down?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding it right away. Set it up as a CROSS-SELL, or an ADD-ON product.

Comment: This is not what we need because the add-on product has its own SKU

Comment: Yah that isn't a problem, you can still use a SKU. Additionally there is a plugin called, forced-sell, which would add a product based upon a different selection.

Answer (score 0):

I would set the product as a simple product and use hooks to add a link to the product with an extension cable